# Use function for mocked class' method return value

Tags: python, testing

I am new to mock and and trying to work with side_effects.

I am trying to set the return value of a method of a mocked class based on the argument said method was called with. In the below code, I am trying to set the return value of `some_function` when having mocked `MyClass`.

```
# application.py
from my_module.my_submodule import MyClass

def my_function(var1):
    instance = MyClass()

    instance.some_function(var1)
```

and my testing file

```
# test_application.py
import mock
import application

def test_my_function():
    with mock.patch('application.MyClass') as MockClass:
        MockClass.return_value.my_function.return_value = some_return

        application.my_function(var1)
```

This works such that `some_function` now returns `some_return`, but I would like to have a function in place of `some_return` which takes the argument `var1` that the function is called with.

The problem is that I don't know how to define the mock to anticipate the calling argument of `some_function`.

I have experimented with what is discussed in this post [changing the side effect of a mock object's method created with patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772036/changing-the-side-effect-of-a-mock-objects-method-created-with-patch), but I can't for the life of me figure out how to format it.

I have tried something like this

```
# test_application.py
import mock
import application

def test_my_function():
    with mock.patch('application.MyClass') as MockClass:
        MockClass.return_value.my_function.return_value = some_return  

        # Breaking very long line, in my code it's actually one line.
        MockDataPrep.return_value.extract_preprocessed_citizen_data.\
        side_effect =\
        mock.MagicMock(side_effect=my_side_effect)

        application.my_function(var1)
```

where the function `my_side_effect` looks like this:

```
def my_side_effect(var1):
    return_val = some_manipulation_of_var1(var1)

    if something:
        return `abc`
    else:
        raise LookupError
```

but it doesn't seem that the `my_side_effect` is ever entered (tried with print statements inside of it). How would I format this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mocking wrong method. `my_function` is a function of `application` module, not a method of `MyClass` and hence what you want to mock is `some_function` instead.

```
import mock
import application


def my_side_effect(*args, **kwargs):
    print("my_side_effect called")
    print(args, kwargs)


def test_my_function():
    with mock.patch("application.MyClass") as MockClass:
        MockClass.return_value.some_function.side_effect = my_side_effect

        application.my_function(arg1)
```

This way `arg1` will be passed to `my_side_effect` within `*args`.

Also, you may want to mock only a specific method, not the entire class.

```
def test_my_function():
    with mock.patch("application.MyClass.some_function") as mock_some_function:
        mock_some_function.side_effect = my_side_effect

        application.my_function(arg1)
```

Comment: This really helped me a lot: thank you. I've linked your answer to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72617873/1599229 .  If you want to answer over there I'll delete my link/sketch

Answer (score 0):

It looks you turned to `side_effects` because you couldn't do it with a `return_value`.

But you can use the `wraps` mock parameter. It wraps an object with a `mock`. You can only use existing methods in the object (although you can add more) and the returned result is the result of the execution of the real method. `return_value` is ignored:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

class Mirror:
    def func(self,x):
        return x

mirror = Mirror()
m = Mock(wraps=mirror)
print(m.func(20))
```

If instead you want to test how a mock was called, with what args, how many times and so on, there are inspection methods in the mock objects too.